# Removing links from articles in Joomla using MySQL query

Tags: mysql, joomla

Trying to use ChristoKiwi's approach with links in Joomla articles, but have issues with this example:

```html
    <p>
   <img
      class="responsive caption"
      style="margin-right: 10px; float: left;"
      src="images/stories/ds/Specials/Mikrosystemtechnik/2019/rohm0119.jpg"
      alt="rohm0119"
   /><a
      dir="ltr"
      title="**Rohm**"
      href="https://www.rohm.de/"
      target="_blank"
      rel="noopener"
      >**Rohm** </a
   >kündigt mit dem BM14270MUV-LB einen der kleinsten berührungslosen
   Stromsensoren der Industrie an. Der neue Baustein verbraucht nur minimal
   Strom und ist mit 3,5 x 3,5 x 1,0 mm sehr kompakt.&nbsp;Damit eignet er sich
   für Industrieanlagen und Verbrauchergeräte, die Betriebsbedingungen über den
   Stromfluss erfassen wie batteriebetriebene Drohnen, Solaranlagen und Server
   in Rechenzentren.
</p>
```

The query

```
UPDATE jos_content SET jos_content.introtext = REPLACE(jos_content.introtext, 
  substring_index( 
    substring_index(jos_content.introtext, 'title="', -1), '"', 1),'')
```

Deletes not only the text within the "title" but also the word "Rohm" after the link.

How to delete the entire link with all the attributes completely?

Comment: This may be an XY problem.  Please post your Joomla questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa. Have posted it there!